# MariaDb/Mysql Query to count nodes in a tree and find largest node

Tags: mysql, graph, mariadb, recursive-query

I have a recursive table to indicate relation of supervision, where a person can supervise many people and get supervised by other many people.

Here a example data:

```
+--------+------------+
| person | supervises |
+--------+------------+
|      1 |          2 |
|      1 |          3 |
|      1 |          4 |
|      1 |          7 |
|      3 |          5 |
|      4 |          5 |
|      5 |          8 |
|      4 |          6 |
|      4 |          7 |
|      6 |          9 |
|      7 |          9 |
|      9 |         14 |
|     14 |         15 |
|      3 |         15 |
|      7 |         10 |
|      7 |         11 |
|      7 |         12 |
|      7 |         13 |
+--------+------------+
```

Can represented by
[image: Recursive table representation]

Of which, blue nodes represents the larger sub-tree and red node represente the root of larger tree.

My problem is, create a MariaDb(10.4.1)/Mysql query that, given a node, for example node number 1:

1. Returns the root with largest amount of nodes

```
select largerId, amount from ....
+-----------+--------+
| largerId  | amount |
+-----------+--------+
|         7 |      5 |
+-----------+--------+
```

2. Return count of max nodes in tree (in that case is amount of 15)

```
select .... where id = 1

+-----------+
| count(id) |
+-----------+
|        15 |
+-----------+
```

other example

```
select .... where id = 7

+-----------+
| count(id) |
+-----------+
|         8 |
+-----------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That doesn't need recursiveness as you're only interested in direct children.

For the first one `GROUP BY person` and limit the result to the top row ordered by the count descending.

```
SELECT person,
       count(*)
       FROM elbat
       GROUP BY person
       ORDER BY count(*) DESC
       LIMIT 1;
```

For the second one count the `UNION` of all values of `person` and `supervises`.

```
SELECT count(*)
       FROM (SELECT supervises
                    FROM elbat
             UNION
             SELECT person
                    FROM elbat) x;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=5c10873316c8149d5e639ae64bd48959)